# ERROR s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'type' cannot appear in element 'element'

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

I have an XML file that I need to read and it looks similar to this:

```
<container time="">
<level1 id="1:0:0" name="Some Name">level1 Description
    <level2 id="1:1:0" name="Some Name">level2 Description
        <level3 id="1:1:1" name="Some Name">level3 Description</level3>
        <level3 id="1:1:2" name="Some Name">level3 Description</level3>
    </level2>
</level1>
```

At build time I am using `xjc` to generate my classes for me.

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${build.dir}/configuration_src"
  destdir="${build.dir}/generated_jars"
  classpathref="example.jars"
  debug="on">
  <include name="**"/>
</javac>
```

The problem I am running into is the fact that `<level1>` has a description but it also has `0 to many` `<level2>`.  How do I setup my schema so that the description gets taken care of?

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/container" xmlns="http://example.com/container" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="container">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="level1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="level1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="level2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="level2">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="level3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="level3">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I try to add a `type="xs:string"` to any of my `<xs:element>` for example
`<xs:element ref="level1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>`

It complains `[ERROR] s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'type' cannot appear in element 'element'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you can't have @ref and @type on the same `<xs:element>` element.

An `<xs:element>` can either be an element declaration, in which case it has an @name attribute and can also have an @type attribute; or it's a reference to an element declaration, in which case it has an @ref attribute and no @type. The type belongs on the element declaration; if you're referring to an element declared elsewhere, then the type goes with that element declaration, not with the reference.

The level3 element is a *complex type with simple content*. The way you declare it is typically

```
<xs:element name="level3">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The level1 and level2 elements are more difficult. They have both text node and element node children. The only way you can describe this in XSD is with "mixed content" types, but mixed content types are designed primarily for narrative text documents, and they can't constrain where the text goes or what form it takes. It might look like this:

```
<xs:element name="level2">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="level3" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Level 3 works like a charm.  Sadly like you said level 1 and 2 are messy.  I end up with `List<Object> content` and the description is mixed in with the sub levels.